# Почему Амазон бот отсылает подозрительные запросы к сайту, тем самым уменьшая производительность сайта?

Tags: sql, wordpress, веб-программирование, amazon-web-services

Нужна ваша помощь в сложном вопросе.

Есть сайт: evroflag.by.
Он находится на одном хостинге другим сайтом компании evroflag24.ru.

Мы замечаем, что в определённое время, сайт начинает притормаживать.

Обратились в поддержку хостинга, они дали ответ, что имеются подозрительные запросы к сайту evroflag24.ru от Амазон бота. Это создаёт нагрузку и тем самым уменьшает общую производительность и скорость.

При этом мы не подключали ни одного сервиса от Амазон.

Помогите разобраться, что это может быть. Это атака на сайт?

Может кто-то сталкивался с похожей ситуацией?

Ответ поддержки прилагаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это разве нагрузка? 4 запроса в минуту...

Comment: @eri , в поддержке сказали что да это "нагрузка" и из-за этого сайты медленные. Откуда вообще берутся эти запросы от бота?

Comment: Может просто парсят сайт. Хотя нагрузка в 4 запроса - копейки. Скорее всего у вас есть неоптимизированный код на бэке или заменяют get запросы так, что бэк вынужден, например, все записи из бд доставать... смотрите, изучайте. Перейдите сами по ссылке с get параметрами и посмотрите что будет

Comment: Поищите вирус. У меня сайт открывался долго - оказалось кусок вредоносного кода там что-то делал. Возможно у вас вирус который реагирует на бота.

Comment: @eri спасибо. можете подсказать что за кусок вреданостного кода? Это мне очень поможет в устранении проблемы?